# Single timer for multiple forms of same list

Tags: timer-jobs

I have created an assessment on SharePoint 2013 and each section of the assessment is in a different form. Only one list is being used.

I want to set a timer of 30 minutes after which the session is to expire after saving the results, whichever form the user is on.

Comment: http://www.sharepointviking.com/a-sharepoint-2010-timer-job-example-with-e-mail-notification/